# Get Pending Invoices by a client

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables.

tbl_Invoice

[image: Invoice]

tbl_Payment

[image: Payments]

**What I want is `List of Pending/Partial  Invoices` by a particular Client.**

What I have tried is:

```
Select * from tbl_Invoice I 
    left join tbl_payment P on (I.client_id = P.client_id 
        AND I.invoice_id <> P.invoice_Id)
    left join tbl_client C on I.client_id = C.client_id
    WHERE I.client_id = 8
```

But It gives me some wrong output.

```
Invoice No  Client Name Date    details             Amount  Paid
----------------------------------------------------------------
ATPL00001   Vishal  10 Dec,2012 Web Designing       100.00  50.00
ATPL00001   Vishal  10 Dec,2012 Web Designing       100.00  10.00
ATPL00001   Vishal  10 Dec,2012 Web Designing       100.00  100.00
ATPL00001   Vishal  10 Dec,2012 Web Designing       100.00  100.00
ATPL00002   Vishal  07 Dec,2012 Software Development        1000.00
```

So I have no idea of how to get Pending/Partial Payed invoices.

Can anybody help.!!

Comment: Start with a good definition of what is and isn't pending and partially payed invoice. These can be quite different categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (*you can add more columns to the second select query from invoice table as required*)

```
;WITH cte (clientid, invoiceid,  amountPaid)
As
(
   Select client_id clientId, invoice_id invoiceId,  sum(amt) amountPaid
   From tbl_Payment
   Where client_id = @YourClientId
   Group by invoice_id, client_id
)
Select client_id, invoice_id, (total_Price - Isnull(amountPaid,0)) toBePaid
From tbl_invoice I Left join cte On I.clinet_id = cte.clientId 
           And I.invoice_id = cte.invoiceid
Where (total_Price - Isnull(amountPaid,0)) > 0
```

Comment: It gives result of Invoice ID `6` only but what about `5 and 7`..??

Comment: @VishalSuthar: This selects invoices which are not fully paid. Filter is done by bottom `Where (total_Price - amountPaid) > 0`. If you need to see them all, comment it out.

Comment: @VishalSuthar: I have done an edit to bring invoices which are not paid at all. With `Isnull()` check. Should be okay now.

Comment: Yes, somehow. but I want all the columns shown in the output of my question.@Kaf

Comment: @VishalSuthar Well, say where do I get the `name` column from. I have sorted the logic for you, sure you can do the rest. (I have mentioned it above my answer - first line)

Comment: Ok fine.. 1 last question. Where can I add `toBePaid <> 0` because I only want pending invoice and not the paid one..@Kaf

Comment: @VishalSuthar: that is what `WHERE` clause is filtering. it does `toBePaid > 0`

Comment: Great..I didn't notice..Thanks for all your help..+1 plus Accept.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select invoice_ID,Client,total_price - Coalesce(AMT,0) as [open]
from
(
select invoice_ID,Client,total_price
,(Select sum(AMT) as AMT from tbl_Payment where tbl_Payment.invoice_ID=tbl_Invoice.invoice_ID) as payed
 from tbl_Invoice left join tbl_client C on tbl_Invoice.client_id = C.client_id
 ) a
 where total_price - Coalesce(AMT,0)>0
```